# How to change the path for logging.file in (logback.xml) for UAT server?

Tags: java, spring, logging, console

I am trying to run a project on a UAT (Linux) server, but there is a problem, I need the logs to be written on the test server in a different path.

The project resources contain logback.xml, which specifies where to write logs:

```
<property name = "logging.path" value = "/logs"/>
<property name = "logging.file" value = "app-logger"/>
```

I cannot change this file, because in this case everything is correct, but for UAT I created another logback.xml and put it not in the resources but in another directory, and when I run the jar file I want to specify that I need to take this one logback.xml

On UAT I execute this command

java -Xmx512M -jar /home/user/app/program/program-0.1.jar --logging.config = app/program/config/logback.xml

I got this error:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender [RollingFile] - openFile (/logs/app-logger.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/app-logger.log (No such file or directory)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration (LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
```

So the second file logback.xml which I created is ignored and the one that lies in the resources is used. What am I doing wrong? How to put another logback.xml into Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in your required log directory to your environment specific properties file,
should be something like application.uat.properties. So you would add in something like `LOG_DIR=path/to/directory`

Once that is done add in '`<property resource="application.${env}.properties"/>`' to your logback.xml

And finally in your file appender , add '`<file>${LOG_DIR}/serive.log</file>`'

Comment: Where can I find file appender? And should I add in execute command  --logging.config = app/program/config/logback.xml  ?

Comment: You will need to add the file appender yourself, I suggest reading this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/logback#2-fileappender . And, no, once you've performed the steps you will not need to use the logging.config flag.